# LEER ARCHIVO VENTAS CSV EN COLAB / JUPYER Y PODER GRAFICAR

Tags: base-de-datos, dataframe, google-colab

Ayudaaaa llevo mucho intentando leer un archivo csv en colab y el problema es que al convertirlo en data frame y luego querer graficar no lo consigo.
Al aplicar describe() no me lee bien los numeros ( son pesos chilenos)

Son las ventas de clientes, les paso el link del notebook en colab.

LINK ARCHIVO
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12r-9zLvAiBiAhVmnn4o46XyxWtFPOBkW/view?usp=sharing

LINK COLAB
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1meE0_7tSO3J69YjZ7X7Oljg__-kMe8hw?usp=sharing

Ayuda please.

Answer (score 1):

He leido el archivo sin mayor problema. ¿Qué te ha mostrado a ti tu programa? COLAB no corre bien para ver lo que has hecho.

Mi código fue:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("lf1.csv", sep=";")
```

Resultado:

```
CLIENTE    int64
ENERO      int64
FEBRERO    int64
MARZO      int64
ABRIL      int64
MAYO       int64
JUNIO      int64
JULIO      int64
dtype: object
```

Al correr:

```
sns.pairplot(df) puedo ver los gráficos
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y finalmente al correr:

```
sns.catplot(data = df, x = "CLIENTE", y = "ENERO") veo:
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que alcance a ver en COLAB es que tienes un error en el código final, es decir, tienes esto:

```
sns.catplot(df = df, x = "cliente", y = "enero")
```

Cuando `df = df` deberia cambiar por `data = df`